# Ability to notify a user - iPhone application

Tags: iphone, notifications, push

I have an iPhone application which is essentially a catalogue, when I add a new product in, can I send a notification to the user on their iPhone?

I want to be able to add a notification through a back end manager, like a web site for example, something that is quick and easy to let people know about a new product.

I know this is possible as I have seen it a few times being used with iPhone applications in the past.

Please can someone point me in the right direction with this? I have read about PushNotifications but can you send them without updating the app every time?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called Push Notifications. You can read everything about it here in the docs http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Edit_: Who told you you need to update the App everytime you want to send out a Push Notification?

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications would be perfect for you. They are messages that you can send to all (or specific) users. When the device receives the message, you can choose to add an icon badge and play a sound. I would first look at this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

After you master that, and you're ready to support all of your users, then go to this site: http://www.easyapns.com

Note: You will not need to update your app every time you want to send a notification. You can send them when you want and theoretically how many you want (check out Apple's guidelines). HOWEVER, you WILL need a server to support push notifications.